# Is it possible using image processing whilst scanning barcodes?

Tags: android, image, barcode

Is it possible to use image processing whilst scanning barcodes? Does it make scanning easier and faster? And Is it possible to do it on Android Studio?

Comment: In general?  Sure.  You can always just take a photo and do whatever you want with it in post processing.  If you mean particular techniques, that's too broad a topic, and you'd need to tell us what libraries you're using to do barcode processing (or if you're doing it by hand).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Faster and easier part can vary from different aspects, not just for the image quality, but it can. Make your tests for various operations done on image (grayscale, brightness, contrast, blur, etc.)

What you have to do is: take the image, process it - before extracting the barcode - through OpenCV or some other image processing library on Android. Then use this processed image on extraction.

- Follow [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html) to install OpenCV to Android Studio
- [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) is the tutorials for basic tasks that can be done on OpenCV (with the examples for various languages like Java, C++, Python)
- And next, you should look for possible image processing techniques to better do the OCR. Internet is full of these kind of Q&A's. Search for it.